# What aspects of javascript are relevant for Selenium Automation (with Java bindings)?

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver, javascript, test-script

I use Java and Selenium for my automation framework. However, sometimes, as per need, I have to use JavaScriptExectutor in my script. But I have never studied JS and no nothing about it. If someone asks me to write JS code, I get confused with the window, functions etc.

What topics should I learn for automation (not as a Developer)

For Ex:

```
public void asynJSMethod() throws InterruptedException {

        System.out.println("Start time: " + new Date());
        JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
        js.executeAsyncScript("alert('Hello');window.setTimeout(arguments[arguments.length - 1], 5000);");
        System.out.println("End time: " + new Date());

    }
```

Comment: "How much javascript" (the original title) was unanswerable so I updated it as shown

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Selenium with Java bindings and are required to use JavaScriptExecutor in your test scripts, it is important to understand the following topics in JavaScript:

1. Variables - You should be familiar with declaring and initializing variables in JavaScript and their types (e.g. string, number, boolean, etc.).
2. Operators - You should understand different types of operators in JavaScript (e.g. arithmetic, comparison, logical, etc.) and how they can be used in your code.
3. Conditional Statements - You should be familiar with using if-else and switch statements to control the flow of your code.
4. Loops - You should be familiar with using for, while, and do-while loops in JavaScript.
5. Functions - You should understand the concept of functions in JavaScript and how to define and call them.
6. Arrays - You should understand how to declare and use arrays in JavaScript.
7. Objects - You should understand the concept of objects in JavaScript and how to create, access, and modify object properties.
8. DOM manipulation - You should understand how to access and manipulate the Document Object Model (DOM) in JavaScript, including elements, attributes, and events.

These topics should give you a solid foundation in JavaScript to work with the JavaScriptExecutor in Selenium.

It is also helpful to have a basic understanding of JSON data format, AJAX calls and promises.

Knowing the basics of these topics should help you write JavaScript code for Selenium automation scripts.

Here are a few resources that can help you get started with JavaScript:

1. Codecademy's JavaScript course - https://www.codecademy.com/learn/introduction-to-javascript
2. FreeCodeCamp's JavaScript course - https://www.freecodecamp.org/learn/javascript-algorithms-and-data-structures/
3. MDN Web Docs - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript
4. W3Schools' JavaScript tutorial - https://www.w3schools.com/js/
5. Eloquent JavaScript - https://eloquentjavascript.net/

I hope this helps!